# Proof verification: Prove that $(s_n) = \sqrt{n^2+1} - n \to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Prove that $(s_n) = \sqrt{n^2+1} - n \to 0$

Can someone verify my proof that the sequence converges to 0?

By the definition of sequence convergence, we must show that for all $e >0$, there exists a natural number N such that if $n > N,$ then $|\sqrt{n^2+1} - n - 0|<e.$ Indeed, let N be the smallest natural number that is greater than $\frac{1-e^2}{2e}.$ Then $|\sqrt{n^2+1}-n|<|\sqrt{N^2+1}-N|<|\sqrt{\frac{1-2e^2+e^4}{4e^2}+1} - \frac{1-e^2}{2e}|=|\frac{1+e^2}{2e} -\frac{1-e^2}{2e}|=e.$ By the definition of sequence convergence, $(s_n)\to0$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. One thing I would note is that you should use $\epsilon$ instead of $e$, **especially** in the context of limits, but mathematically your proof is good.

Answer (score 1):

I dislike this 
"pulling a magic formula out of a hat" technique. 
In my opinion, 
it it much more useful and instructive
to show how the formula was derived.

Here is what I would do:

In this case,
we want
a condition on $n$
such that
$|\sqrt{n^2+1}-n| < \epsilon
$.

Using the standard technique,

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{n^2+1}-n
&=(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\\
&=\dfrac{(n^2+1)-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\\
&<\dfrac{1}{2n}
\qquad\text{since } \sqrt{n^2+1} > n\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $\dfrac{1}{2n} < \epsilon$,
which is the same as
$n > \dfrac1{2\epsilon}$,
$|\sqrt{n^2+1}-n|
< \epsilon$.

Also,
I see no need
for the slightly better bound
$\dfrac{1-\epsilon^2}{2\epsilon}
$,
especially since
no derivation was
given for it.